# Two identical posts, captured by Graph API as different status_fbid items

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone explain the difference between these two stories?

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=169103046454071&story_fbid=627951107235927

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=169103046454071&story_fbid=627936823904022

Both came from the same Graph API call, at different moments. They have the same information displayed in slightly different ways. And, most importantly, both have different FBIDs.